# Hadrash V'HaIyun on Parashas Vaera: translation request

Tags: commentaries, translation, va-eira

In sefer Hadrash V'HaIyun, [Rabbi Aharon Levin](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%9F_%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%99%D7%9F) comments on Parashas Vaera. However, I am not able to understand these concepts. Can somebody maybe translate it, maybe that would help me in getting understanding of it.

Rabbi Levin discusses the idea that a prophet can give different messages upon people.

**Message 1:** this is given upon a sinful nation. The prophecy deals with bitter visions and tribulations that will befall a sinful nation.

**Message 2:** this is given to a nation that is in distress and wants to walk in Hashem's ways. When a nation is in distress, Hashem will appear and tell them that their future will be bright.

I suppose Rabbi Levin is connecting message 2 to this week's parasha (Vaera). That G-d promises Moshe Rabbeinu that He will take B'nei Yisrael out of Mitzrayim, free them, make them unto a nation etc...

Furthermore, Rabbi Levin discuss the idea that G-d put Moshe Rabbeinu in charge of this special mission. He says something like "these two concepts, e.g. walking and have a mission are united with each other".

The above is stated on [this page](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20413&st=&pgnum=42).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He's saying that Hashem sends prophets for two reasons: either to bear good tidings or warnings of punishment. The former Hashem calls שליחות; the latter, הליכה, as though to distance Himself from the assignment.

That's why, in [Yeshayahu 6:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.6.8?lang=bi), when Hashem wants to reveal both the troubles that will befall the Jews as well as the news of their ultimate redemption, He asks את מי **אשלח** ומי **ילך** לנו, but Yeshayahu only responds הנני **שלחני**, because he only wanted to be an agent for good news.

Moshe also had both jobs: On the hand, he was sent to redeem the Jews from slavery; on the other, he was an agent of retribution against the Egyptians, as hinted in the dual language of [Shmos 3:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.3.10?lang=bi&aliyot=0), ועתה **לכה ואשלחך**. But Moshe also wasn't happy about being an agent of retribution. And once his talk with Pharaoh backfired on the Jews, Moshe additionally felt justified in complaining to Hashem ([Shmos 5:22](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.5.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.5.22&lang2=bi)) למה זה **שלחתני**. As Rashi explains, וא"ת מה איכפת לך קובל אני על **ששלחתני**, meaning, "Even though it's not my place to question Your decision, how can this be called שליחות? Where's the good news?"

Hashem's response, as explained in Rashi ([Vaera 6:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.6.2?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.6.2&lang2=bi)), addresses both points. On the issue of הליכה, there's no reason to be reluctant because that mission comes with a great reward too: נאמן לשלם שכר טוב **למתהלכים** לפני. On the question of שליחות, have a little patience; it is indeed a mission of good which will ultimately benefit the Jews, fulfilling the promise made to your forefathers: לא לחינם **שלחתיך** כי אם לקיים דברי שדיברתי לאבות הראשונים.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you! Hatzlacha!